# How do I load image dataset from google drive to google colab so that I'd train my model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I just downloaded caltech256 dataset in my drive and want to load it in my colab so that I'd use it to train my model.
How do I do that?
or is there a better way ?

this is what I did so far

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

then

```
!tar -xvf "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data_Clatech256/256_ObjectCategories.tar" -C "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Data_Clatech256/"
```

I can read and write files from drive, but how do I load the data ready to train ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) with `.flow_from_directory(directory)`. The ImageDataGenerator allows you to do a lot of preprocessing and data augmentation on the fly. By calling `.flow_from_directory(directory_of_your_ds)` you can then build a pipeline to your drive. Have a look at an example from the documentation to get more insights:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did to load the data from the disk to ram to image data generator

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

import pathlib
data = pathlib.Path('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data_Clatech256/256_ObjectCategories') 

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        data,
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        )
```